# Angular component is not getting Google Chart reference

Tags: angular, typescript, charts, angular7

I want to use google chart in my angular application. But the problem is google is coming as undefined every time.

In my Index.html I have added

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
```

In my component I have declared this below import section:

```
    declare var google: any;
```

In OnInit I have written this:

```
google.charts.load('current', { 'packages': ['corechart'] });
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(() => this.drawChart());
```

I have searched on internet also. Every solution is saying that put the js reference in index.html and use it in component by declaring it. What I am doing wrong here? Can anyone suggest me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use npm install angular-google-charts to install google charts. Also check if you have imported google charts in your app-module.ts file.

Comment: My UI developer has given me an html content and in that content she is referencing it from www.gstatic.com. Are you sure installing it through npm will work.

Comment: It should work.You can see this for your reference https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/different-way-of-implementing-google-column-chart-in-angular-7

Comment: Happy to help .